# How to pass username password to Gradle to upload artifacts to Nexus from a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I need to upload artifacts to Nexus from a Jenkins declarative pipeline. There is a [Nexus plugin](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/227256688-How-do-I-configure-the-Nexus-Jenkins-Plugin) that I can't use because it doesn't allow to publish SNAPSHOTs. Therefore I have to upload them directly through the Gradle upload task. The problem is that I am getting a 401 error code from Nexus and it seems the nexus user and passwords aren't being passed from the pipeline to the `./gradlew upload` task.

This is my current configuration:

**Pipeline**

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'asdf23432-fe69-1234-2222-ffa65yteec2c', passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_USER')]) {
    sh "./gradlew upload --debug"
}
```

**Gradle**: In the ext section I try to access the NEXUS_USER and NEXUS_PASSWORD variables from the withCredentials step.

```
ext{
    nexusUser = System.properties['NEXUS_USER']
    nexusPassword = System.properties['NEXUS_PASSWORD']
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            snapshotRepository(url: 'http://somerepo'){
                authentication(userName: nexusUser, password: nexusPassword)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the variables as system properties using this:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'asdf23432-fe69-1234-2222-ffa65yteec2c', passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_USER')]) {
    sh "./gradlew -DNEXUS_PASSWORD=$NEXUS_PASSWORD -DNEXUS_USER=$NEXUS_USER upload --debug"
}
```